# Clojure namespace not resolved

Tags: clojure, namespaces, leiningen

in one file (core.clj) I have

```
(ns nac.core)
(def bar "something")
```

And in another file in the same directory, I have

```
 (ns nac.io
  (:require [nac.core :as c]))

 (defn foo [] c/bar)
```

Upon evaluation I get an error saying

```
 Unable to resolve symbol: c in this context
```

So the file is found in the require, but the namespace as I have named it is not.

What am I missing here? Thanks.

Comment: How are you running this?

Comment: I am running this using Nailgun in Vim, setting up the project using Leinengen

Comment: Check out tim pope's vim-foreplay. It's a much better alternative to vimclojure's nailgun stuff.